# Getting started with laravel testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, refactoring

I'm trying to get to grips with testing and am trying to go about testing an app I'm developing. Not quite TDD so not starting from a good place but I thought testing on a partially built app with working functionality would be easier (wrong!).

I've created many of my controllers using Jeffrey Ways generators which also creates the test. I've then modified those controllers to enable my app to do the things I need it to. I've set up phpunit, installed mockery and I've bought the book testing decoded and working my way through it. I can't though make the leap on testing a method I created ie how do I test this and more importantly what should I be refactoring - I need a kick start...

So - here's my controller for a particular method that creates a book of tickets and then creates each individual ticket:

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()

/**
 * Validation rules required:
 * 1. start and end numbers must be unique
 * 2. start number must be less than end number
 * 3. start and end numbers must not exist in ranges created by other books eg overlap
 * 4. must contain date, user
 */
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $validation = Validator::make($input, Book::$rules);

    $input['assigned_date'] = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd/m/Y', Input::get('assigned_date') )->format( 'Y-m-d' );

    if ($validation->passes())
    {
        $book = $this->book->create($input);

        //once created then create tickets:
        TicketAudit::batchcreate($input['start_number'],$input['end_number'],$book->id);

        return Redirect::route('books.index');
    }

    return Redirect::route('books.create')
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
}
```

and here's a test I'm working on:

```
public function testStore()
{
    $input = array(
        'assigned_date'=>'13/11/2013',
        'start_number'=>100,
        'end_number'=>200,
        'assigned_owner'=>'test user'
        );
    Input::replace($input);
    $this->mock->shouldReceive('create')->once();
    //$this->validate(true);
    $this->call('POST', 'books', $input);

    $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('books.index');
}
```

I'm not convinced I've handled the dummy user input correctly. Also I don't know how I should isolate or test the part of the method that creates the tickets - should this be refactored - if so how? I also get error validate method not found so commented this out for the time being.

I want to start testing with a view to learning how and create better code - can anyone point me in the right direction to get me started on this method

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m not familiar with laravel, but I dont think you need the `Input::replace` call. You are in fact passing the `$input` into the `$this->call() ...` method.

Then there is the `shouldReceive` method on your "Facades" which Laravel makes heavy use of.

http://laravel.com/docs/testing

So `TicketAudit::shouldReceive('batchcreate')->once();` could be a useful assertion.
As that is extracted already it makes sense to have a seperate test for that method.

Comment: Thank you - this worked - I also discovered factoryMuff which helps with a load of other tests. Thanks